# About ssh to wireless server

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I am running a raspberry pi as home server. I find that I cannot access service via my desktop but I can access it by my laptop via wifi connection.
desktop -> lan cable -> router -> wifi -> pi (not working, error: No route to host)
laptop -> wifi -> router -> wifi -> pi (working)

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution. It is solved by enabling vpn passthrough setting (ipsec pptp and l2tp) in netgear router